# Code to differentiate the Layout for Mobiles and Desktops in Emails

Tags: php, html, email, media-queries

I am using PHP function to send emails with some custom body message. I want to display that body message differently in desktops and mobiles. I am using @media CSS but it is not working. Can somebody provide the solution with an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know which mail client you are using to know if it is supporting media queries. Please take a look at this link to find out, what is not supported in many mail clients:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/

If you want solid styling for different devices and software I suggest you use products like [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com) for Newsletters or [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) for transactional emails.

Both provide a variety of bullet proof templates you can use right away.

Answer (score -1):

1)You can redirect mobile users to a different page with different css styles.You can differentiate between mobile and desktop with php.
OR
2)You can use bootstrap to make your webpage.

personally i think the 2nd option is better

Comment: This has nothing to do with styling the mail itself.